# how to get a data which is not entered in the specific date and also get the data which is entered in the specific date in tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I am creating a report for a retail shop in which i need to give a product in stock per day so i used the entry date as a parameter to filter the data but the problem here is the items which are not entry on that specific day is not coming on the report i need the report to be like

```
if parameter=entrydate then product in stock else preveious product in stock
```

i.e if the item is not entered in that particular date it should give the past record of it. how to get that please help me with this

Regards,
Jen

Comment: Hey, seems pretty straight forward but not sure what sort of variable "previous product in stock" is? Could you give us a subset the data your tying to achieve this on?

Comment: Previous product in stock means past record if the A is not entered on may 26th it should give the may 25th or previously when A has been entered data